# Friendly Spider found at home, London

Tags: species-identification

What kind of spider is this? It was very friendly and shy, we spotted it inside our house and we carefully took it to the forest. Hope it will be a nice environment for this kind of spider... One of my kids loves to play with spiders and I would like to be advised on what kind os species he can approach or not. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jason, for decoding the image! Why was it coded? Would like to know how to avoid it next time.

Comment: Just to be sure: is it London, UK you are located at?

Comment: London, UK yes.